# What does "DLBU" stands for in Mali GPU?

Tags: arm, gpu, mali

What's full name of DLBU? What's the usage of it? Thanks.
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/mediatek/+/android-mtk-3.18/drivers/misc/mediatek/gpu/gpu_mali/mali_utgard/mali/mali/common/mali_dlbu.c?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Load Balancing Unit. You'll see it spelled out on [line 111](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/mediatek/+/android-mtk-3.18/drivers/misc/mediatek/gpu/gpu_mali/mali_utgard/mali/mali/common/mali_dlbu.c?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F#111).
This unit dynamically assigns work to the pixel processing cores that are enabled in the PP_ENABLE_MASK register.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I think that's true what it means.